# Google adsense application rejected - network website

Tags: wordpress, google-adsense

I'm running a network of websites/subdomains, that are all based on the same `samedomain.com`, each subdomain having its own `subdomainaddress.samedomain.com`.

On the front page of `samedomain.com` the content is added by pulling posts(about 30 of them in total) from each subdomain, and a small excerpt of their post content. When the user clicks on a post title from the front page of `somedomain.com`, it will point to the original post from the `subdomainaddress.samedomain.com/somepost/`.

**Some background:**

- The website is driven through Wordpress multisite network with subdomains;
- the same template page is used on each front pages of the subdomains aswell as for the main domain;
- only thing different between the **front pages** of the `subdomain` and the `domain` itself is the way that the links point to (for the subdomains, for example 30 posts with excerpt will point to their internal url, while for the main domain, 30 posts with excerpt will point to the subdomain that the post came from );
- we went with this structure of `domain - subdomain` relation with wordpress multisite network mainly because we have many categories and posts, and so it makes it easier to organize things;
- ever subdomain gets properly indexed by google and all the other search engines, while the original domain does not.

So far I've tried applying for google adsese program, and I got reject because of content quality I believe, mainly:

- Don't place ads on auto-generated pages or pages with little to no original content

I understand the issue with this, however maybe someone out there has an idea on how to solve it; maybe point out somehow that all these external links from the front page of the `domain.com` point to the original content, and somehow say this is just a front page to show off our top posts, or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to solve it is to write "your own" original content for the page.

I understand what you're saying. In a sense it is original and it is yours, however; as far as Google is concerned the content is being "pulled in" from "outside" ergo... it is not "original". It is not "yours" it belongs to the sub-domain.

Perhaps make it more of an "about us" page describing all of the types of content available throughout your site, the topics covered, etc. (includes the sub-domains) and then make sure the "pulled in" content does not exceed the "original" content. This gives more weight to the "original" content.

You might also want to reduce the number of posts being pulled in from your sub-domains.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yeah we figured that it may work like that, however, since we don't really have any posts in the main domain(except for some blog-posts and some static pages), so we're back to square one.

Comment: Not necessarily. As I stated... put some original text on the home page and just make sure it's not overshadowed by the content you pull from your sub-domains. Otherwise you will just have to live without adsense until Google decides to change their rules.

Comment: Currently we're modifying the structure, add some content about whats goinn on the the domain and so on, and hopefully it will get accepted. If not, moving on :) Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt that the rejection of your adsense account happened just because of the site structure. It may have been rejected due to several other reasons including overall little to no original content on your website (including your sub-domains).

However, if you are very sure that you have enough good content on your sub-domains and the only possible explanation is the site structure then, I have couple of suggestions for you -

1. Have a slightly different copy of excerpts on domain.com. You can ask your dev to include additional custom field on wordpress for this. This excerpt for each post will be shown only on the domain.com and so you will have original content on the homepage with only links to sub-domains.
2. Reduce the number of outbound links (including subdomains) from your homepage. Lot of outbound links indicate low quality content.
3. Also, as Kuya suggested, you should create some original content just for domain.com - may be you can include a blog. Also, include privacy policy page on domain.com.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The content on the subdomains is alright, the problem is with the main domain, as stated above. We're thinking about a different approach on how to handle this, as right now it does have lots of outbound links that point to each of the other subdomain, and less to nothing related to the main domain.